# IntelliJ Gradle Sync Error

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle

I recently upgraded to IntelliJ 2017.2.4 and can no longer sync my Gradle app. This prevents the dependencies from being downloaded which in turn prevents my app from building.

I can build from the command line but cannot download dependencies or 'sync' / 'refresh' from Gradle.

I'm using Gradle 4.1

Error:

```
Message Gradle Sync
Gradle Project Refresh Failed
Error:org.gradle.tooling.LongRunningOperation.setEnvironmentVariables(Ljava/util/Map;)Lorg/gradle/tooling/LongRunningOperation;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that IDE patch update went wrong (because some jars were locked by the OS). [Reinstalling](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) IntelliJ IDEA should help.

Comment: Cleaned and reinstalled. Works 100%